# Consultation automate EJB Timer

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb-3.1

How do I monitor the ejb timer I have in my application.
example:
I need to be sent an e-mail admnistrador User when the ejb fail.

Today the view is done manually by accessing the link glassfish: / ejb-timer-service-app / timer and when it is verified that no ejb is active, the application has to be restarted.

Answer (score 0):

If your question means you want to access timer functionality in JavaEE in more convenient way, than accessing via JNDI, the you would use `TimerService` or `@Schedule` annotation - more details in [Java EE tutorial secion](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html).

You may inject `TimerService` into your EJB using `@Resource` annotation:

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean
@Startup
public class IntervalTimerDemo {

    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        timerService.createTimer(1000, 2000, "IntervalTimerDemo_Info");
    }

    @Timeout
    public void execute(Timer timer) {
        System.out.println("Timer Service : " + timer.getInfo());
        System.out.println("Current Time : " + new Date());
        System.out.println("Next Timeout : " + timer.getNextTimeout());
        System.out.println("Time Remaining : " + timer.getTimeRemaining());
        System.out.println("____________________________________________");
    }

}
```